# Перевод из восьмеричной в заданную систему счисления

Tags: c, системы-счисления

Как правильно вывести второе число в восьмеричном виде?
Числа в десятичной 405, -1540264186, 3488987754, 1508439372, 3040177432

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int perevod(long long x, long long ss)
{
    long long A[50];
    int i=0,j=0;
    while (x>0)
    {
        A[i] = x-((x / ss)*ss);
        x = x / ss;
        i++;
    }
    for (j = i - 1; j >=0; j--)
    {
        if (A[j]<10) printf("%lld", A[j]);
        else printf("%c", A[j] + 55);
    }

    printf(" %lld\n",ss);
    return(0);
}
int main()
{
    short a1;
    int a2;
    unsigned int a3;
    long a4;
    unsigned long a5;
    a1 = 0625;
    a2 = 0-13363510372;
    a3 = 022426570152;
    a4 = 013172172514;
    a5 = 026515266430;
    printf("short %o=", a1);
    perevod(a1, 33);

    printf("int -%o=-", -a2);
    perevod(a2, 29);

    printf("unsigned int %o=", a3);
    perevod(a3, 12);

    printf("long %o=", a4);
    perevod(a4, 26);

    printf("unsigned long %o=", a5);
    perevod(a5, 28);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a2 = 0-13363510372;` не является восьмиричным строковым литералом, а является десятичным (а минус тут бинарный оператор), ноль и минус все же нужно поменять месатами.

Отрицательные числа в любой системе счисления выводятся в дополнительном коде.
выглядеть будет вот так

> int -1540264186 // base 10
>
> int 024414267406 // base 8